# Google Analytics API Filter for Index/Homepage

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to figure out how to construct a filter that will retrieve just the pageviews of my homepage using the Google Analytics API. I can get pageviews of other pages, for instance:

`ga:hostname==mydomain.com;ga:pagePath=~/my-page/$`

But I want pageviews of just `mydomain.com/`. I've tried the following and they don't work:

`ga:hostname==mydomain.com;ga:pagePath=~//$
ga:hostname==mydomain.com;ga:pagePath=~///$
ga:hostname==mydomain.com;ga:pagePath=~/\//$
ga:hostname==mydomain.com;ga:pagePath=~/[\S]{1}/$`

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ga:pagePath==/
```

If you want to use a regular expression, it would look like this:

```
ga:pagePath=~^/$
```

Here's a [demo of this query](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&dimensions=ga%3Ahostname%2Cga%3ApagePath&filters=ga%3Apagepath%3D%3D%2F) using the Query Explorer:

Comment: One small correction, the second one should read `pagePath`, not `pagepage`.

Comment: Thanks! Technically it works with either, but I've updated it so there's no confusion.

Comment: ga:page**Path** =~^/$ was necessary for me. I was getting empty results with pagePage

Comment: @WebandFlow Thanks for catching that! I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Sam Sorry, when I originally read your comment I thought you were just talking about the capitalization, and technically (at this time) dimensions are case insensitive.